Flutter + Java Spring Boot + OAuth2 - how to setup
I'm struggling to setup a new project using Flutter + Java Spring Boot + OAuth2.
(I'm fairly new to all 3 of these, but I'm doing it to learn so I want to use these technologies specifically, and I don't want to use a 3rd party auth provider like FireBase (don't want to ultimately be locked in)).
I have a lot of questions as I can't find clear documentation, but if anyone can point to an example/tutorial for this scenario, that would help.
This is where I am:
SpringBoot:

Java Spring Boot, with spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client and web etc.
@EnableWebSecurity to setup the securityFilterChain - '/login' does not need auth
LoginController mapping '/login'
Setup an account in google console, and added keys to application.property files for clientid etc

This seems to work - I can see it seems to login OK (although I can't figure out what happened or the next steps).
This is where it gets probematic.  I'm not sure how Flutter should be connecting to my server to authenticate, nor how to get the token, and pass this to my server.
What I don't understand:

How should flutter access Spring Boot?  I had some flutter code that calls 'oauth2/authorization/google', and I can 200 being returned, but the response seems to be the google web page
Does/should the OAuth call go through my server?  Or does Flutter directly access Google?
Is there a flutter package that is recommended to handle this, or since I'm not using a provider, do I need to directly use http.get ?
I imagine I need to get the token, save it to FlutterSecureStorage, and then set this in the header for any call to the server?
In flutter am I expected to check every call to see if the access has expired?

A bonus question is, for a flutter app (Android/iOS/Web) to access my server, presumably I have to turn of CORS (@CrossOrigin) on Java side?  I'm concerned about security though.
Really appreciate any directions!

I updated an answer to another question with details to authorize requests from a mobile app to a Spring application with oauth2Login

Requests to Spring clients with oauth2Login are authorized with session cookies, not with Bearer tokens. So you'll have to be careful with the user agent with which your mobile device sends the authorization code to the Spring backend after it receives it from the authorization server. I detailed the steps in this other answer.
As you are concerned with security:

be sure to keep protection against CSRF enabled on Spring OAuth2 clients with oauth2Login. Again, it is based on sessions which are the vector for CSRF attacks. in the case of mobile & single page applications, you'll need cookie-based protection.
do not try to make your Flutter app a public OAuth2 client (talk directly to Google and fetch tokens), even with PKCE. Using confidential clients is safer than public ones, and tokens are safer on the server, away from device storage, and hidden from the frontend dependencies code.

You should consider using your own authorization server. When directly using "social" identities like you do, you can't manage user data in tokens (stuff like "roles" is a requirement in most apps), and you can't manage token format. Also, this would make the addition of more identity sources easier (an LDAP server, more OpenID providers like Facebook & Github, etc.). I wrote a tutorial to get started with Keycloak. You could also consider cloud offerings like Auth0 & Amazon Cognito. The Spring Authorization Server is another option, but requires more work and a better knowledge of the OAuth2 & OIDC standards than you probably have.
If your backend grows and you want to split it into several (micro or not) services talking to each other, you'll probably want these services to be configured as resource servers with a gateway in front of them. In this situation, have a look at the OAuth2 BFF pattern for which I wrote another Baeldung tutorial.
